# How can I extract hidden content from a remote web page using PHP?

Tags: php, deobfuscation

I want to read a website with php (file_get_contents?), which is hidden with <span style='display:none;'>.

4 examples:

1. U<span style='display:none;'>wsebv</span><u></u>rfahr
2. Z<span style='display:none;'>e<i></i>i<span></span>nhv</span><b></b>öhrdorf
3. B<i></i>a<i></i>b<span></span>e<i></i>n<span style='display:none;'>einhv</span><u></u>berg
4. K<span style='display:none;'>s<i></i>d<span style='display:none;'>d<span style='display:none;'>b<span style='display:none;'>n<span style='display:none;'>v<i></i>b<span style='display:none;'>h<i></i>gawe</span><u></u>aoi</span><b></b>hvws</span><b></b>aoir</span><b></b>asud</span><b></b>asu</span><b></b>irchdorf/Kr.

Results should be:

1. Urfahr
2. Zöhrdorf
3. Babenberg
4. Kirchdorf/Kr.

Two possible approaches for solving the problem (but I don't know how to implement them):

A) Remove all span-tags with their content

B) Programatically read only VISIBLE content

Many thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: so what did your two approaches do? Show some code

Comment: Uwsebvrfahr - does it come in html? And in browser it looks like Urfahr? If so, then it can be only javascript decoded (you may check it by disabling Javascript in browser and reload the page). You need to find this javascript and analyze the encoding algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, remove `<span>` tags - a simple regex will do the trick.

Comment: >so what did your two approaches do?  I don't know how to implement them......

Comment: if that's 'encryption' them i'm viewing source on my banks website.

Comment: That's not encryption, it's mild obfuscation...

Comment: @Dagon, My wonderful bank disallows right-click AND opening links in new tabs for "security reasons".  :-D

Comment: i think most people know how to get around  that

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.fussballoesterreich.at/netzwerk/datenservice/379402779304830775_O~733830065019629299~744933674800963515~0~1.htm');

$i = 1;
foreach($html->find('.mannschaft a') as $e)
{
    $x = html_entity_decode($e->innertext, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $x = preg_replace('#<(.*)>#', '', $x);
    echo $i, '. ', $x, '<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

Result:

> ```
> 1. Garsten
> 2. S. Valent.ASK
> 3. Bumgartenberg
> 4. Neuhofen/Krems
> 5. Admira
> 6. Asten
> 7. Enns
> 8. Pasching 1b
> 9. S. Florian 1b
> 10. SValentin SC
> 11. Hörsching
> 12. S Ulrich
> 13. Wdischgarsten
> 14. Doppl-Hart
> ```

My work here is done.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's a good solution, but not working when nested spans are used!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a style is applied makes no difference.  To PHP, it's just a bunch of text.

Try:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://....';  // URL you're scraping.
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$text = strip_tags($html);
echo "<PRE>$text</PRE>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Try it with the following code, search in browser-output for the 3rd occur of "Ergebnisse" and look at the obfuscationed line.

<?php
$url = "http://www.fussballoesterreich.at/netzwerk/datenservice/379402779304830775_O~733830065019629299~744933674800963515~0~1.htm";

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$text = strip_tags($html);
echo "<PRE>$text</PRE>";
?>